# How to have more than 5 tabs in react-native-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Is it possible to get more than 5 buttons in the tab bar? I know it is not recommended (due to UX), but I am building an app for tablets, not phones and there is really plenty of space and I would really like to have 7 buttons. 
Any way to make it possible with this framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible as RNN uses https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation which doesn't support this.